# How to prevent a data feed from creation of duplicate records in RSA Archer platform?

Tags: archer, rsa-archer-grc

I have 3 seperate applications:

1. Risk Libraby
2. Processes
3. Risk Application

Processes can be associated with multiple risks from the Risk Library (through a cross-reference). One process can be associated with many risks from the Risk Library (P1 -> R1, R2 and P2 -> R2, R3, R4).

End user may come at any time and add risks to a process record.

A data-feed runs which creates individual records in the Risk Application for every associated risk depending on the values in the cross-reference in Processes application, like shown below:

P1 -> R1

P1 -> R2

P2 -> R2

P2 -> R3

P2 -> R4

AND deletes the associations from the cross-reference in Processes application (so that the cross-reference is empty after the feed runs).

Now, I want a way in which I can prevent duplicate records being created in the Risk Application. For eg. if P1R1 record is already created in the Risks App, and the end user after 2 months again associates R1 to P1 (in the cross reference) it should not create P1R1 again in Risk Application.

I hope I have made it clear. Any solution or some other work-around to this requirement will be benevolently appriciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting case you described there.
First of all, I think that you are not providing a complete picture of the relationships/design you have in place.
[image]
Look at the diagram I created based on your requirements. You said that your data feed creates new records in the Risk Application and at the same time updates records in the Processes application. This is impossible to do so within the same data feed unless these two applications are linked via another cross-reference. Or you are using another data feed to update records in the Processes application ( and you didn't mention this).
I will try to provide you best answer possible based on what you have shared. I assume that there is a link between Rick Application and Processes application even though you didn't mention it.
1. Update your data feed configuration to make sure that it will only create new records in the Risk Application.
2. Update your data feed to use a combination of "Process" + "Risk" as a key during the import. Corresponding field should be created in the Risk Application. Note that you don't have to modify the key field in the Risk Application itself. You can calculate string value for this import key in the data feed itself. If you do so, with "Create Only" and a data import key "Process + Risk" your data feed will be creating new unique records only.
3. Using a missing link between Risk Application and Processes, given data feed can override cross-reference pointing to the Risk Library located in the Processes application. You can use a static text field to override it within the data feed itself.

Tanveer,
This solution should work.
Note - this is the best answer I can give you based on the limited info you have shared.

Good luck!

Comment: Great solution @Stan... combining the key fields worked like a magic trick.

Just for my info, is there any website where Archer developers share their questions and solutions. I ask this since archer developers are not very active on stackoverflow.

Comment: @TanveerShaikh I use RSA Archer Community page to ask Archer directly functionality and bugs related questions. RSA monitors these questions and forum Admins reply to them usually in 24 hours.
But they don't offer solutions to the "creative" questions like you asked.
I think that most of the Archer developers are there and you can ask for their help on RSA Archer Forum.
Would be nice to have some questions covered here as well though.

Comment: Sorry but can you please have a look at this too... your expertise would be of great help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31316679/validation-for-not-allowing-same-users-to-be-selected-in-record-permission-field